# Get Resource Id For Google Drive API Android

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am using the drive api to create a file in the hidden app folder on google drive. I want to get the resource id of that file but it keeps on returning null. Here is the code. Once it creates the file it is supposed to get the file resource id in the call back but it returns null. It gets the normal drive it ok but that does not help at all since the fetch drive id need the resource id. any idea on how to get the resource id. I have checked multiple different links about this and all of them are no help.

```
//<editor-fold desc="Variables">

// Define Variable Int MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE//
public static int MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;

// Define Variable int RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE//
public static final int RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE = 3;

// Define Variable GoogleApiClient googleApiClient//
public GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

// Define Variable String title//
String title = "Notes.db";

// Define Variable String mime//
String mime = "application/x-sqlite3";

// Define Variable String currentDBPath//
String dBPath = "/School Binder/Note Backups/Notes.db";

// Define Variable File data//
File data = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

// Define Variable File dbFile//
File dbFile = new File(data, dBPath);

// Create Metadata For Database Files//
MetadataChangeSet meta = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder().setTitle(title).setMimeType(mime).build();

String EXISTING_FILE_ID = "CAESABjaBSCMicnCsFQoAA";

//</editor-fold>

// Method That Runs When Activity Starts//
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initiate allowWriteExternalStorage Method//
    allowWriteExternalStorage();

    // Initiate connectToGoogleDrive Method//
    connectToGoogleDrive();
}

// Method That Runs When App Is Resumed//
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Checks If Api Client Is Null//
    if (googleApiClient == null) {

        // Create Api Client//
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    // Attempt To Connect To Google drive//
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

// Method That Runs When App is paused//
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    // Checks If Api Was Used//
    if (googleApiClient != null) {

        // Disconnect From Google Drive//
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

// Method That Runs When App Is Successfully Connected To Users Google Drive//
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    // Add New File To Drive//
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(contentsCallback);

}

// Method That Runs When Connection Is Suspended//
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

// Method That Runs When App Failed To Connect To Google Drive//
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    // Checks If Connection Failure Can Be Resolved//
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {

        // If Above Statement Is True, Try To Fix Connection//
        try {

            // Resolve The Connection//
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ignored) {
        }

    } else {

        // Show Connection Error//
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, connectionResult.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
    }
}

// Method That Gives App Permission To Access System Storage//
public void allowWriteExternalStorage() {

    // Allow Or Un - Allow Write To Storage//
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Request To Write To External Storage//
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    }
}

// Method That Connects To Google Drive//
public void connectToGoogleDrive() {

    // Create Api Client//
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    // Attempt To Connect To Google drive//
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

//<editor-fold desc="Contents Callback">

// What Happens When App Is Trying To Make A New File Or Folder//
final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> contentsCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {

        // Runs When File Failed To Create//
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

            // Log That File Failed To Create//
            Log.d("log", "Error while trying to create new file contents");

            return;
        }

        // Checks If Creating File Was Successful//
        DriveContents cont = result.getStatus().isSuccess() ? result.getDriveContents() : null;

        // Write File//
        if (cont != null) try {
            OutputStream oos = cont.getOutputStream();
            if (oos != null) try {
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
                byte[] buf = new byte[5000];
                int c;
                while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                    oos.write(buf, 0, c);
                    oos.flush();
                }
            } finally {

                oos.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Put File In User Hidden App Folder//
        Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(googleApiClient).createFile(googleApiClient, meta, cont).setResultCallback(fileCallback);
    }
};

//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold desc="File Callback">

// What Happens If File IS mAde Correctly Or In-Correctly//
final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {

        // Checks If It Failed//
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

            Log.d("log", "Error while trying to create the file");
            return;
        }

        Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(googleApiClient);

        Log.d("log", "Created a file in App Folder: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());

        String File_ID = String.valueOf(result.getDriveFile().getDriveId().getResourceId());

        Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(googleApiClient, File_ID).setResultCallback(idCallback);
    }
};

//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold desc="Id Callback">

final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveIdResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

            Log.d("Message", "Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");

            return;
        }
        DriveId driveId = result.getDriveId();
        DriveFile file = driveId.asDriveFile();
        file.getMetadata(googleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(metadataCallback);
    }
};

//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold desc="metadata Callback">

final private ResultCallback<DriveResource.MetadataResult> metadataCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveResource.MetadataResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveResource.MetadataResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                    Log.d("Message", "Problem while trying to fetch metadata");
                    return;
                }
                Metadata metadata = result.getMetadata();

                Log.d("Message", "Metadata successfully fetched. Title: " + metadata.getTitle());
            }
        };

//</editor-fold>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't do like that, let extends `DriveEventService` to handle that task:

```
public class GoogleDriveEventService extends DriveEventService {
    private static final String TAG = "GoogleDriveEventService";

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(CompletionEvent event) {
        super.onCompletion(event);
        DriveId driveId = event.getDriveId();
        String resourceId = driveId.getResourceId();

    }    
}
```

**UPDATE** `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service
    android:name="training.com.services.GoogleDriveEventService" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.drive.events.HANDLE_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: how do I incorporate this into my code above? thank you for the response though :)

Comment: Just create new class. And it will work like broadcast receiver for you. Always run that method after you upload file into drive. Dont forget define this with your manifest file. Im not online in pc so i cannot post it for you. I will post it later

Comment: And what method am I running, or how do I use GoogleDriveEventService class as a method after I upload the file

Comment: it's auto run onCompletion after you upload a file. so you can do everything in that (send resourceId to other activity, etc...)

Comment: i added the Class to my application, and updated the manifest but when i debug the app the class does not run after the file is created how do i get the app to run the code

Comment: Take a look at here: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/completion#handle_a_completionevent

Comment: is my code above calling upon DriveEventService because this class never gets called?

Comment: It's called automatically after you define it in AndroidManifest.xml file. onCompletion() auto called when you upload file into Drive. anyway, if my answer is helpful, plz accept it

Comment: Hi did it help you? So consider accepting my answer that the others can use this solution.

Comment: Sorry It didn't work for me, instead I queried the app folder in google drive and, using its metadata got the resource Id that way. @bui Quang Huy